# coeftest vcovHC gives me NaN while estimating standard error

Tags: r, regression, nan, plm, standard-error

I'm trying to estimate day-of-week or month-of-week (etc) effect on daily returns of some crypto, i have dummy for each day of the week and for each month of the year, i also have a panel for about 5 years of daily return, but when i try to regress on a single crypto (the aim is to analyze the effect for each crypto i have) the coeftest function with vcovHC gives me NaN on some days (or months)

My panel is made predominantly by dummies, like ContG, who takes 1, 2 (..) if the day is monday, tuesday (etc), but there are more for months and other effects i'd like to study.
For example, i ran a

```
formula <- plm(Return ~ 0 + factor(ContG), data = filter(data.p, Crypto=="ETH"), model = "pooling")
coeftest(formula, vcov. = vcovHC(formula, cluster = "group"))
```

but the results shows up with columns of NaN for Standard errors, t-value and p.

```
t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate  Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)    
factor(ContG)1  7.1662e-02         NaN       NaN       NaN    
factor(ContG)2 -1.4370e-03  4.9752e-09   -288828 < 2.2e-16 ***
factor(ContG)3  1.1981e-01         NaN       NaN       NaN    
factor(ContG)4 -4.1304e-01         NaN       NaN       NaN    
factor(ContG)5  1.7603e-01         NaN       NaN       NaN    
factor(ContG)6  5.1917e-01  1.5636e-09 332038379 < 2.2e-16 ***
factor(ContG)7  1.1773e-01         NaN       NaN       NaN    
---
```

Moreover, when i don't use vcovHC the problem doesn't occur
i don't know what i am doing wrong, but R returns me these results for other regressions too.
The problem don't show up when i try to regress using the lm function, but i feel like it's not the correct way. I don't understand if the problem comes by using plm, by using traditional vcovHC, or by using the pooling, even if i tried using the model=within and it also gaves me those NaNs